# SQLClient What error numbers are related to SQL Server Connection errors so I can retry

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient

I get the following error with SQLClient. Are there more error numbers than Error Number: -1, 53, 2?

> Error Number: -1, Level: 20, State: 0, Line: 0; Message: A
> network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
> a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
> accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
> Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
> Specified)
>
> Error Number: 53, Level: 20, State: 0, Line: 0; Message: A
> network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
> a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
> accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
> Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
> Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> Error Number: 2, Level: 20, State: 0, Line: 0; Message: A
> network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
> a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
> accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
> Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
> Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Please try following link for details of errors 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645611(v=sql.105).aspx

The error codes are returned by the db server to the sql slient.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav Singh Jantwal, this is what I was looking for. Now how do I mark this questions answered?, is it because yours appear as a comment and not as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following link for details of errors

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645611(v=sql.105).aspx

The error codes are returned by the db server to the sql client.

**Update**

Try the latest database events and errors here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors

Comment: I can't imagine why this answer was down-voted into the negatives.  It's essentially correct, unless people care to explain their downvotes. I'm upvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

The rules I use for general classification:

- Number = -1 OR Class/Level/Severity = 20: "Connection Error"
- Number = -2: "Command Timeout Error"

I believe the negative values are strictly from the client library (ie. network connection issues); this implies the "duplicate" numbers like 2 and 53 come back from the server itself for half-connections.

Other errors (eg. deadlocks/1205) can be more readily defined by the Number.

---

As the other answer contains, here is also a link to various references:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645611.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number.aspx